# Comment dire « go take a flying leap » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Je voudrais dire ceci en français : « They can go take a flying leap. »

Je connais « aller se faire foutre », mais je cherche quelque chose plus gentil et moins choquant.

Du contexte : « They » sont des gens très suffisants et ainsi l'image d'un « flying leap » est marrant.

Answer (score 8):

Pour garder le côté imagé et humoristique :

> Ils peuvent (toujours) se brosser

Answer (score 8):

Une version un peu plus pondérée peut être :

> Qu'ils aillent se faire cuire un œuf !

Answer (score 7):

Probablement :

> Ils peuvent aller se faire voir.

Comment: Pour moi, "aller se faire voir" est en effet la version "plus gentille et moins choquante" de "aller se faire foutre". Dans le contexte donné, ça rend bien !

Comment: Même si le mot voir est utilisé, je trouve qu'en français cela reste relativement vulgaire. Et il me semble, sans en être sûr que "flying leap" en anglais a une connotation négative moindre.

Comment: @user2010913 Si « aller se faire foutre » est vulgaire et choquant, « aller se faire voir » l'est beaucoup moins ou pas du tout suivant le contexte, ce qui réponds il me semble à la question posée et ne justifie pas un vote négatif.

Answer (score 3):

Même ordre d'idée :

> Je m'en vais te les envoyer valser.

Answer (score 3):

Pour conserver l’idée de "flying leap" essaie,

> Ils peuvent aller se jeter d'un balcon.

ou

> Ils peuvent aller se jeter d'une falaise.

Answer (score 3):

Voici des expressions sans la vulgarité de celle citée : "va te faire voir ailleurs" ou "tu peux aller te faire voir".

Answer (score 2):

J'aime bien : « Va donc faire un tour ».

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression signifie aussi que l'on en n'a rien à faire. Dans cet ordre d'idée je propose quelques possibilités de traductions.

Pour une connotation historique:

> Je m'en lave les mains (Ponce Pilate, qui n'en n'avait clairement rien à faire de Jésus).

Sinon il existe des expressions très fleuries pour exprimer cela:

> Aller au diable
>   Aller péter dans les fleurs (Québec)
>   Aller niquer sa mère (à éviter)
>   Aller se faire enculer (idem)
>   Aller se faire voir chez les Grecs (France)

J'en passe et des meilleurs...

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas la variante québecquoise et elle est excellente, il faut l'avouer.

Comment: Il faut savoir que la variante québécoise n'est utilisé qu'à des fins humoristiques et n'est que peu utilisée dans des conversations normales. On utilise "Aller voir ailleur" plus régulièrement