# Expression du futur proche et connotations avec la forme « s'en aller »

Tags: sens, pronoms, futur-proche

Le futur proche [Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-12541.php) s'exprime au moyen de « aller » conjugué au présent et suivi de l'infinitif du verbe dont l'action est future.

Ce futur s'exprime aussi, bien que beaucoup plus rarement, en remplaçant « aller » par « s'en aller » dans la construction habituelle. Cette construction est d'autant plus rare qu'elle ne s'emploie plus qu'à la première personne du singulier.

> (**LBU 14<sup>e</sup> édition § 820 a) 1°**) *S'en aller* s'emploie aussi pour un futur proche, mais surtout à la 1<sup>re</sup> personne du singulier de l'indicatif présent.
> • *Je* M'EN VAIS *faire moi-même au lecteur les honneurs de ma personne*
> (TAINE, Vie et opinions de Fr.-Th. Graindorge, p. 12).
> À d'autres personnes, cela est archaïque  :
> • *Bientôt une partie de ceux que nous n'avons pu rompre [...]* S'EN VONT *être appelés par le péril russe* (BARRÉS, Union sacrée, p. 98).
> [S'en est supprimé dans la réédition : Chron. de la Grande Guerre, 1.1, p. 147.]

*[Un exemple récent](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/monde/sommet-russie-afrique-les-tensions-entre-dirigeants-africains-ont-%C3%A9clat%C3%A9-au-grand-jour/ar-AA1euXxf?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=711cf3c8a3da418e81d688359ee7413d&ei=6)*

- Le président de la transition au Burkina Faso s'est adressé frontalement à la vingtaine de chefs d'État et de gouvernement réunis autour de Vladimir Poutine : « Je m'en vais m'excuser auprès des anciens que je pourrais vexer dans mes propos à venir. Les questions que nos générations se posent sont les suivantes : il s'agit de comprendre comment […]

Quelle serait la différence que l'utilisation de « en » entrainerait ? En d'autres termes, y a-t-il des connotations attachées à cette variante et si oui que peut-on en dire ?

Comment: Quelle serait une expression équivalente sans le _en_?

Comment: Quelle est la raison de ce vote négatif ? Rien ne le justifie.

Comment: @LPH Ce n'est pas grave. Pense à tous les votes positifs injustifiés qui tu as reçus et tu verras que tu es gagnant ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Vos considérations à propos d'être gagnant ou pas ne me concernent pas. Je ne fais pas une course. Ce qui m'importe c'est de ne pas être lésé de façon flagrante. Il y a des jours et des jours que quelqu'un met des votes négatifs sans raison à mes questions et à mes réponses et cela n'arrivait pas auparavant,. Pour ce qui serait de votes injustifiés, c'est votre opinion personnelle, pas la mienne : je ne vois pas pourquoi mes votes seraient injustifiés et les votes des autres utilisateurs tous parfaitement justifiés.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais dit ça. J'ai moi aussi très certainement reçu des votes positifs injustifiés. C'est la vie...

Comment: @jlliagre : **que tu as reçues**, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris ***Que** tu as reçu**s*** Lapsus calami :-)

Answer (score 4):

Le futur composé remplace souvent le futur simple un peu de la même façon que le passé composé s'est substitué au passé simple.

Bien qu'il soit appellé *futur proche*, il peut être utilisé pour des événement lointains, voire très lointains :

> *Le soleil va s'éteindre dans 5 millions d'années.*

La forme utilisant *s'en aller* au lieu d'*aller* ajoute parfois une information de déplacement qui précède l'action du verbe.

Il peut aussi y avoir une recherche d'effet littéraire, régional ou comique suivant le contexte.

Quelques exemples d'utilisation (c'est moi qui graisse) :

> Accablé des malheurs où le destin me range,
> **Je m'en vais les pleurer**. Va, cours, vole et nous venge.
> Corneille, *Le Cid*, 1637.

> Il me prie de lui dire la vérité; **je m'en vais la lui dire**.
> Madame de Sévigné, Lettres, 1726.

> Alors Abisaï, fils de Sarvia, dit au roi : Faut-il que ce chien mort maudisse le roi mon seigneur ? **Je m'en vais lui couper la tête**.
> *La sainte Bible*, II S 16,9, trad. Sacy, 1701.

> Je l'ai promis à M. Lempereur et **je m'en vais lui mander que j'ai eu l'honneur de vous écrire**.
> Bossuet, *Lettres diverses*, 1692.

> Secret stratégique, mh? Le temps qu'ils refroidissent, **je m'en vais te les vous cuisiner un peu**, moi !
> Greg, *Achille Talon a un gros nez*, 1982.

> **Je m'en vais te les envoyer valser**.
> Stéphane Gimenez, [2014](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9283/1109).

Comment: Intéressant, recherche d'effet littéraire, régional ou comique…

Comment: Ou emphase, sans nécessairement un déplacement actuel: _il s'en va lui signifier derechef que c'est injuste_, par exemple. Ou bien: _nous nous en allons de ce pas déclarer victoire_. Dans ces cas-là, je dirais qu'il y a simplement emphase sur l'intention.

Comment: Les deux exemples de LBU ci-dessus à mon avis n'impliquent pas non plus un déplacement actuel.

Comment: Plus tu ajoutes des exemples, moins j'ai l'impression que _s'en aller_ implique un déplacement actuel ;-)

Comment: @Frank *Actuel* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Dans le sens d'_effectif_, par opposition à _virtuel_?

Comment: @Frank [Tu baignes trop dans l'anglais](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/17007571/vrai) ;-)

Comment: Je viens de modérer ce point.

Comment: Oui, trop d'anglais :-)

Comment: Mais ce sens d'_actuel_ existe aussi en français apparemment: j'ai vérifié et trouvé ce sens dans un dictionnaire, ce qui m'a surpris.

Comment: @Frank C'est vrai, c'est même le premier sens du Littré.